# This my script that check a number is prime or not, but when the number is 99 or 77, the scripyt failed to check, why? how to fix it?

Tags: python

```
num = input("Please enter an integer: ")
def is_Prime():
    h = num / 2
    for x in range(2, h +1):
        if (num%x) == 0:
            return False
    return True
def main():
    if is_Prime():
        print num, "is a prime number"
    else:
        print num, "is not a prime number"
main()
```

Comment: @user497786: Where is the if statement at int(h) != h

Comment: int(h) != h  is not useful, I had del

Comment: I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding how this code works. IMHO you should get out a pen and paper and step through it line by line to get a feel for what happens at e.g. 99.

Comment: I'm embarrassed for the people who are voting this question up.

Answer (score 1):

You are always returning true or false after checking divisibility with 2:

```
for x in range(2, h + 1):
    if (num%x) == 0:
        return False  # <<< here
    else:
        int(h) != h
        return True   # <<< and here
```

Also I'm not sure what the line `int(h) != h` is supposed to do. You are evaluating an expression and then discarding the result.

Try this instead:

```
for x in range(2, h + 1):
    if (num % x) == 0:
        return False
return True
```

Regarding the line `h = num / 2` the upper limit of `num / 2` will work, but actually you only need to check up to `math.sqrt(num)`.

Comment: oh sorry, the int(h)!= h is not useful

Comment: oh, I don't know math.sqrt(num), do you have simply way?

Comment: @user497786: `sqrt` gives the square root of a number (when you multiply the square root with itself, you get back the original number). It is possible because when you can divide a number `a`, lets say 14, by two numbers `b` (the larger one) and `c` (the smaller one) (in this case, `b` is 7 and `c` is 2), you just need one of them. And the smaller one has to be equal or less than `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_Prime():
    h = num / 2
    for x in range(2, h +1):
        if (num%x) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have fixed the problems with your script with your edit.  However, there a few more things you could improve.

You should really be passing the number you're testing to the function, rather than accessing at as a global variable.

The call to `input()` should really be inside the `main()` function.

Also, you can simplify your loop by using [the `all` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
def is_Prime(num):
    h = num / 2
    return all(num % x != 0 for x in range(2,h+1))
```